# How to pull properties from `createMuiTheme` inside Material-UI `ExpansionPanel`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI and I have a component which is their [ExpansionPanel](https://material-ui.com/demos/expansion-panels/). I also created a default theme with `createMuiTheme` and I want most of the styling come from there. I want to set the color of my expansion panel to grey as it was defined in `createMuiTheme` however this didn't succeed neither using MUI `className` nor using `style` within the expansion panel. This is the code of my panel:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ExpansionPanel from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel';
import ExpansionPanelSummary from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary';
import ExpansionPanelDetails from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
  },
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.grey
});

function SimpleExpansionPanel(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  console.log(`theme.palette.secondary.grey=${classes.backgroundColor}`);
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ExpansionPanel className={classes.backgroundColor}
                      style={{ backgroundColor: classes.backgroundColor }}>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>More Info</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
            sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
    </div>
  );
}

SimpleExpansionPanel.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(SimpleExpansionPanel);
```

Specifically, the line `console.log(`theme.palette.secondary.grey=${classes.backgroundColor}`);` prints: `SimpleExpansionPanel-backgroundColor-332`.
And this is the code of my `createMuiTheme`:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';

const MaterialBlueTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
    secondary: {
      main: '#f50057',
      grey: '#BDBDBD'
    }
  },
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
  }
});

export default MaterialBlueTheme;
```

Lastly I'm using MUI context to provide the theme:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import App from './App';
import MaterialBlueTheme from './components/layout/MaterialBlueTheme.js';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<MuiThemeProvider theme={MaterialBlueTheme}>
  <App />
</MuiThemeProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

How can I really use the color I want from the `createMuiTheme`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every key in your styles object is a css classname. Every value must be a valid CSS properties object. Therefore:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
  },
  // should use a better name for this class i.e. use a semantic name
  backgroundColor: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.grey,
  }
});
```